# how to fix 417 exception failed issue in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

how to fix 417 exception failed issue in Jmeter

[image: 1]

We were checking the breakpoing of a usecase-
tried to disable all the html and css files still issue persist

Answer (score 0):

As per [417 Expectation Failed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/417) documentation:

> The HTTP `417 Expectation Failed` client error response code indicates that the expectation given in the request's [Expect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect) header could not be met.
>
> See the [Expect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect) header for more details.

It means that your server returns other [HTTP Status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) than [100](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/100) so either check your server logs to identify the reason or remove the Expect header from the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) (or maybe apply it to the request where the header is needed, see JMeter User Manual chapter on [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) for more details)